# Difference between "don't need to/needn't" & "don't have to" & "needn't have to"

Tags: grammar

Example:

> I can manage the shopping alone. You ____ come with me.

Are those just the same thing? I mean it sounds natural if I interchange each of those, but let's see the example from my book:

> - Everything **will** be OK. You **needn't worry**. (It is not necessary)
> - Everything **was** OK. You **needn't have worried**. (you worried, but it was not necessary)

Does that mean **needn't have** is used when something *is done* and **needn't** is used when something *is going to happen* or what?

What about **don't have to**?

And consider about this:

You ______ anymore.
Which one should I put? "will" and "was/were" are not mentioned. In this case I don't know if the thing is going to happen or has happened.

Comment: There is no ***needn't have to*** construction in English with the sense of *need not **be obliged to** [do something]*. The word ***have*** in ***You needn't have worried*** is only there because it's part of the Present Perfect construction ***[you] have worried***.

Comment: **You needn't have worried** (no _to_) - You _were_ worried about a situation, but there was no need to because it turned out well. **You needn't worry** - everything is OK now, or a future situation is expected to turn out well. **You don't have to worry** means the same. **You don't have to worry any more** - things _have_ turned out well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two ways of expressing the same thing. In modern American vernacular you will not hear "needn't" used, unless it is ironically or to hark back to older ways of speaking.

Also, "you needn't have (done something)" would be a rough equivalent of "didn't have to do (something)."

You needn't have shot the man.
You didn't have to shoot the man.

Those mean the same thing.